# How many are the boolean vectors of length $n$ having at least one element equal to $1$?

Tags: probability, statistics

How many are the boolean vectors of length $n$ having at least one element equal to $1$?

First of all, what is a boolean vector? It's a variable composed by two elements which are $0$ and $1$? So what does it mean that its lenght is $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A boolean vector of dimension n is a vector with n coordinates each equal to either 0 or 1.

For example : (0,0) is a size 2 boolean vector.

The only vector to have no element equal to 1 is (0,..., 0), and since there are $2^n$ boolean vectors, there are $2^n -1$ boolean vectors with at least one element equal to 1.

Edit : Another way to put it is that a boolean vector of size n is an element of $\{0, 1\}^n$

Comment: So for example this boolean vector 00000 and this 000 are the same?

Comment: They are not. 00000 is a boolean vector of size 5 while 000 is a boolean vector of size 3.

Comment: how many are the boolean vectors of length n that only have the first two elements equal to 1?

Comment: For n=3 those elements are 110 and 111, for n=4, 1100, 1101, 1110, 111, and I'll let you figure out by yourself for n > 4. As a result there is $2^{n-2}$ vectors with that property.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "how many"

Comment: By the way 111 is wrong because "Only the first two elements must be equal to 1"

Comment: My bad, I misread your question, if you want to have only the first 2 elements equals to 1, then all the following elements must be equal to zero, and only one such vector exists.